# Emacs org-mode: how to hide the details of plain list items by default

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Suppose we have this in org file:

```
* Shopping
I'm going to buy these items in the grocery;

1. item1
    wow, fantasy
2. item2
    emmmmm
```

when i `<tab>` the headline `Shopping`, it display the details of plain list items.

what i want is below instead:

```
* Shopping
I'm going to buy these items in the grocery;

1. item1...
2. item2...
```

I have try add both `#+STARTUP: overview` and property `:VISIBILITY: folded`, but neither of them works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(setq org-cycle-include-plain-lists 'integrate)` should fix your issue.

From the docs: If this variable is set to integrate, plain list items will be treated like low-level headlines.